# How do I get a list of users that are not on the last command? (Not logged in recently)

Tags: gnu, last

I need a list of users that I cannot find by using the `last` command (i.e. they were not logged in recently).

Would a temporary file be useful for this?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you those who were seen from the 'last' command in a file called 'last.txt'.

```
last | cut -f1 -d' ' | uniq | sort | grep -v reboot | grep -v wtmp | egrep -v "^$" > last.txt
```

This gives you those all users on the system in a file called 'passwd.txt'.

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d: | uniq | sort > passwd.txt
```

Interpreted correctly this gives you the difference. Namely, "those who are not on the last command".

```
diff last.txt passwd.txt
```

This is easier to look at though.

```
sdiff last.txt passwd.txt | less
```